# C#: Sane alternative to optional parameter in property?

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-3.0, properties

Given: a class with properties like SomeNumber that, *internally* can be null (i.e. `int?`), but externally, you typically don't want to handle that special case, and pretend they start out as zero. So far, we're always returning a non-nullable version, i.e. `int`. I'd like to add an option to have a nullable version.

**The easiest variant:** Two properties. Works great, but unfortunately clutters the class with lots of largely redundant options. External code:

```
return myObject.SomeNumber; // Not nullable.
return myObject.SomeNumber_Nullable; // Nullable.
```

**The internally dirty, but externally nice variant:** A property with an optional parameter. I haven't yet found out how to do this in C#; .NET Reflector seems to be omitting incorrect code. In VB.NET, it looks like so:

```
Private _SomeNumber As Nullable(Of Integer)
Public Property SomeNumber(Optional ByVal AllowNull As Boolean = False) As Nullable(Of Integer)
  Get
    If Not AllowNull AndAlso _SomeNumber Is Nothing
      Return 0
    End If

    Return _SomeNumber
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
    _SomeNumber = value
  End Set
End Property
```

External code:

```
return myObject.SomeNumber; // Not nullable.
return myObject.SomeNumber(true); // Nullable.
```

Among the disadvantages:
* C# implementation is so ugly .NET Reflector doesn't even seem to know how to do it,
* I find the general notion of parameterized properties questionable,
* In the non-nullable example, the return type doesn't match the actual behavior of the property — the compiler now thinks it *can* be `null`, but it really can't.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Define "internally" -- does that mean within the class or within the application?

Comment: I guess I'm missing the point, since clearly you are exposing the knowledge to the client, ie...they have to pass a bool to get what they want. What is the harm in it just being a int? If they want the value call Value on it, they can check if it has a value or not. If the null is not needed, use -1 as that is common practice for int types which are not nullable...

Comment: Internally means within the class; externally outside the class or in a different assembly. -1 as a pseudo-null value won't do me any good because it's a valid number, i.e. could be the actual value.

Comment: ...and the reason using the standard null type won't suffice? The consumer either has to pass in a bool or call Value on the type...I'm not seeing the difference, nothing is being abstracted here...

Comment: Sure it is. `int?` allows `null` (obviously), which the class consumer's code would then have to check for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties cannot have parameters in C#, so if you want to use property syntax you'll need two properties with different names.

If you don't want users of your class to be aware of the fact that internally your field could be null, its pretty straightforward if you control the implementation of your property.  Define the backing field of your property to be of type `int?`, but leave the type of your property as `int`.

For example:

```
private int? _someNumber = null;

public int SomeNumber { 
  get { return _someNumber.HasValue ? _someNumber.Value : 0; }
  set { _someNumber = value; }
}
```

Now, internally, you can always access `_someNumber.HasValue` to check if a value has been set or not.

However, when you say "I'd like to add an option to have a nullable version.", if you *do* want a way to expose to your client whether or not `SomeNumber` has a value then you have a few options:

- Expose a property like `bool SomeNumberHasValue`
- Change the type of `SomeNumber` to `int?`
- Add a second property `SomeNumberNullable` that has a return type of `int?`

However, a single property cannot sometimes return `int` and return `int?` other times.

Another option would be to use a method to access the value, like so:

```
public int? GetSomeNumber(bool canReturnNull)
{
    if (canReturnNull)
        return _someNumber;

    return _someNumber.HasValue ? _someNumber.Value : 0;
}
```

In effect, you're doing a lot of work to make it easy for your clients to handle a null check, without hiding the fact the value can be null.  What's the benefit?

Comment: I want users of the class to optionally (but not typically) access a version of the property that can return `null`, an effect much like overloading in methods.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are trying to over-design your class. A property is null, or it is not, and it's not a burden for the client to check for nulls. I would find it a burden to understand your API, which to me sounds something like: 'This property is never null. Unless you check to see if it really is null.' Huh?

Also, trying to hide null values is generally a bad idea because it hides errors in your program.